# Const-correctness with proxy object

Tags: c++, templates, const-correctness

I am confused with the following code, where the class `Baz` gives access to its internal data through the proxy class `Bar`:

```cpp
struct Foo{};

template<class T>
struct Bar 
{
    Bar(T &val_): val(val_) {}

    T &val;
};

struct Baz 
{
    Bar<const Foo> get() const {return Bar<const Foo>(foo);}
    Bar<Foo>       get()       {return Bar<Foo>      (foo);}
    Foo foo;
};

struct FooBaz
{
    FooBaz(Baz &baz_): baz(baz_) {}
    // Bar<const Foo> get() const {return baz.get();} // this do not compile
    Bar<const Foo> get() const {return const_cast<const Baz &>(baz).get();} // the const_cast seems to be required
    Baz &baz;
};
```

It seems that I must do a `const_cast` to dispatch to the right `Baz::get()` function.

The first thing that I don't understand is that it works if the `FooBaz::baz` is a plain `Baz` and not a reference:

```cpp
struct Foo{};

template<class T>
struct Bar 
{
    Bar(T &val_): val(val_) {}

    T &val;
};

struct Baz 
{
    Bar<const Foo> get() const {return Bar<const Foo>(foo);}
    Bar<Foo>       get()       {return Bar<Foo>      (foo);}
    Foo foo;
};

struct FooBaz
{
    FooBaz(Baz &baz_): baz(baz_) {}
    Bar<const Foo> get() const {return baz.get();} // Ok
    Baz baz;
};
```

What I understand about a const function member is that it makes the `this` pointer-to-const, but in fact it is not totally clear to me what it means... Do all the data member be 'as if they are const'? Is there a clear reference to that?

Another interesting thing is that if I use a `std::reference_wrapper` as proxy class, then it works without the `const_cast`:

```cpp
#include <functional>

struct Foo {};

struct Baz 
{
    std::reference_wrapper<const Foo> get() const {return std::cref(foo);}
    std::reference_wrapper<Foo>       get()       {return std::ref (foo);}
    Foo foo;
};

struct FooBaz
{
    FooBaz(Baz &baz_): baz(baz_) {}
    std::reference_wrapper<const Foo> get() const {return baz.get();} // Ok
    Baz &baz;
};
```

What is the magic with the `std::reference_wrapper`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must do a `const_cast` to dispatch to the right `Baz::get()` function.

Yes. Or `std::as_const`, or make `Bar<T>` convertible to `Bar<const T>`.

> What I understand about a const function member is that it makes the this pointer-to-const, but in fact it is not totally clear to me what it means... Do all the data member be 'as if they are const'?

Yes, the members behave as if they were `const`.

> The expression `E1->E2` is exactly equivalent to `(*E1).E2` for built-in types; that is why the following rules address only `E1.E2`.
>
> In the expression `E1.E2`:
>
> 2. if `E2` is a non-static data member:
>
>    if `E2` is of reference type `T&` or `T&&`, the result is an lvalue of type `T` designating the object or function to which E2 refers,
>    otherwise, if `E1` is an lvalue, the result is an lvalue designating that non-static data member of `E1`,
>    otherwise (if `E1` is an xvalue (which may be materialized from prvalue)), the result is an xvalue designating that non-static data member of `E1`.
>
>    If `E2` is not a mutable member, the cv-qualification of the result is the union of the cv-qualifications of `E1` and `E2`, otherwise (if `E2`
>    is a mutable member), it is the union of the volatile-qualifications
>    of `E1` and `E2`;
>
> — [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators)

When accessed through a pointer to `const` class, its members become `const`.

But the constness is only added at the top level. If you access `int *member;` through a pointer to `const`, it becomes `int *const member;`, not `const int *const member;`.

References work in a similar way, but since references themselves can't be `const`<sup>1</sup>, their type is not changed.

> if I use a `std::reference_wrapper` as proxy class, then it works without the `const_cast`

That's because it a has a constructor that allows `std::reference_wrapper<const T>` to be constructed from `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, a reference can't changed to point to a different object after it's created, but formally it's not `const`. `std::is_const` returns `false` for references.

Answer (score 3):

> it works if the `FooBaz::baz` is a plain `Baz` and not a reference:

That's the point. In `const` member function, the data members are considered as `const` too. Note that for reference, that means the reference member itself is considered as `const`, not the object being referenced. i.e. `baz` would be considered as `Baz & const` (const reference) but not `Baz const &` (reference to const). References can't be const-qualified in fact and the const-ness is just ignored, as the effect, even in `const` member function, `baz.get();` will always call the non-const `Baz::get()`.

It doesn't change for the `std::reference_wrapper` version, `baz.get();` still calls the non-const `Baz::get()` and returns `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`. `std::reference_wrapper` has a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper), the returned `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>` could be converted to `std::reference_wrapper<const Foo>`, which stores a reference to the object got from `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>` (via the
[conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get)).